# R transform two coordinate columns to a vector (point) column and keep it numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
    Stroke ID (starttime)   sx      sy    time Point ID
               <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
1                      0 667.750 824.250     0        1
2                      0 668.500 824.500    53        2
3                  10412 231.250 602.250 10412        3
4                  10412 194.375 526.500 10852        4
5                  11726 226.125 603.500 11726        5
6                  11726 212.250 584.000 14766        6
7                  16355 422.125 665.625 16355        7
8                  16355 468.250 576.500 16635        8
9                  17103 406.750 647.625 17103        9
10                 17103 420.000 663.875 18089       10
```

**sx** and **sy** are the coordinate columns I want to convert into one point column. In advance, I want to apply a euclidean distance function between points in this column later on *(like `sqrt(sum((point1-point2)^2)))`* so the column has to stay numeric. What I have tried till now is following:

```
sxvector <- mydf[['sx']]
syvector <- mydf[['sy']]
points <- paste(sxvector, syvector, sep=" ")
```

which gives me

```
[1] "667.75 824.25" "668.5 824.5" "231.25 602.25" "194.375 526.5"                 
[5] "422.125 665.625" "468.25 576"
...
```

which looks pretty good, but is of course now of type `character`.
When I try to convert it into numeric with `as.numeric` or `factor()` or `unclass()` or any combination of these, I only end up in having NAs. So I think this is a deadend (I would be glad if you prove me wrong!). I then went for

```
coordframe <- data.frame(mydf$sx, mydf$sy)
coordlist <- c(t(coordframe))
```

which again gives me a good looking result like

```
[1] 667.750 824.250 668.500 824.500 231.250 602.250 194.375 526.500 226.125
...
```

which is also still `numeric`. Now I want to create a column I could put into my `dataframe`, which got always two following values combined as a vector as one row, which is still numeric. For example:

```
     Points
1 667.750 824.250
2 668.500 824.500
...
```

To achieve this I used

```
split(coordlist, ceiling(seq_along(coordlist)/2))
```

And I get something looking like this

```
$`1`
[1] 667.75 824.25

$`2`
[1] 668.5 824.5
...
```

but each of these things is of type list, which I cant convert to numeric,too, and cant make calculations with.

Any idea how I manage this? Did I miss something trivial?
edit:I added my data below

```html
structure(list(Stroke.ID..starttime. = c(0, 0, 10412, 10412, 
11726, 11726, 16355, 16355, 17103, 17103, 21190, 21190, 21390, 
21390, 21596, 21596, 21839, 21839, 22433, 22433, 22589, 22589, 
23603, 23603, 23848, 23848, 24028, 24028, 24199, 24199, 24607, 
24607, 24805, 24805, 24939, 24939, 25081, 25081, 25253, 25253, 
25464, 25464, 43614, 43614, 44773, 44773, 47376, 47376, 50808, 
50808, 51943, 51943, 53701, 53701, 54610, 54610, 56108, 56108, 
56804, 56804, 57054, 57054, 58576, 58576, 59118, 59118, 59444, 
59444, 59824, 59824, 60122, 60122, 62233, 62233, 63029, 63029, 
64355, 64355, 69213, 69213, 69509, 69509, 69722, 69722, 69892, 
69892, 70013, 70013, 70157, 70157, 71192, 71192, 71479, 71479, 
72044, 72044, 72537, 72537, 72837, 72922, 72922, 73260, 73466, 
73466, 73650, 73787, 73787, 81336, 81336, 81460, 81460, 81766, 
81766, 82220, 82220, 82266, 82266, 82545, 82545, 85603, 85603, 
92315, 92315, 92493, 92493, 92877, 92877, 93045, 93045, 93171, 
93171, 93460, 93460, 103099, 103099, 104463, 104463, 114168, 
114168, 117497, 117497, 117816, 117816, 118039, 118039, 118268, 
118268, 118490, 118490, 118696, 118696, 118886, 118886, 119084, 
119084, 119269, 119269, 119434, 119434, 119578, 119578, 119741, 
119741, 119924, 119924, 120312, 120312, 120497, 120497, 120682, 
120682, 120861, 120861, 121007, 121007, 121174, 121174, 121316, 
121316, 121475, 121475, 121623, 121623, 121767, 121767, 121916, 
121916, 122089, 122089, 122214, 122214, 122640, 122640, 129695, 
129695, 129952, 129952, 130387, 130387, 130792, 130880, 130880, 
131388, 131388, 151617, 151617, 152471, 152471, 154769, 154769, 
155339, 155339, 155686, 155686, 155873, 155873, 156133, 156133, 
156287, 156287, 156395, 156395, 170859, 170859), sx = c(667.75, 
668.5, 231.25, 194.375, 226.125, 212.25, 422.125, 468.25, 406.75, 
420, 471.125, 472.75, 462.625, 479.25, 477.75, 482.625, 488.75, 
498.875, 493.375, 494.5, 505.875, 511.25, 489.25, 486, 495.625, 
498.625, 497, 500, 508, 513, 512.75, 522.375, 516.25, 516.625, 
519.5, 522.375, 519.125, 520.25, 523.75, 528.75, 530.125, 538, 
264.5, 258.25, 256.75, 49, 63, 278.75, 65, 55.25, 64.375, 203.375, 
43.375, 24.375, 34.125, 134.25, 28.375, 26.875, 28.375, 27.25, 
45.5, 58.625, 35.5, 38.25, 38.75, 41.75, 37.625, 44.375, 42.625, 
47.5, 53.75, 59.375, 24.5, 23, 55.625, 96.5, 34, 96, 305.25, 
305.25, 309.875, 312, 309, 310.875, 316.625, 318.125, 313.75, 
320.625, 321.75, 321.625, 348.25, 350.25, 356.625, 361.75, 311.125, 
323.375, 327.75, 332.75, 331.5, 334.75, 343.75, 342, 349.25, 
356.5, 350.875, 358.375, 375.5, 325, 331.5, 329.5, 337.375, 337.875, 
346.375, 348.75, 348.375, 347.125, 356.125, 355.5, 373.25, 315.875, 
359.125, 35.375, 45.875, 36, 46.875, 40.875, 49.125, 36.75, 35.625, 
50, 54.375, 47.375, 57.75, 210, 85.25, 239, 92.5, 280.375, 467.625, 
12.125, 30.75, 39.375, 55.5, 66.75, 80.125, 90.75, 104.5, 108.625, 
117.75, 123.25, 136, 144.25, 156.875, 165.5, 178, 187.375, 196.25, 
205.875, 213.875, 221, 230.75, 235.5, 249.75, 260.875, 265.75, 
277.375, 287.125, 292.375, 301.125, 312, 319.75, 334.5, 343.5, 
353.875, 364.5, 378.875, 389.375, 401, 412.25, 422.625, 431.25, 
440.25, 445.875, 451.25, 456.125, 460.375, 461.75, 464.25, 465.5, 
463.625, 463.875, 453.375, 471.5, 412, 414.125, 407.25, 414, 
424.625, 434.375, 430.875, 435.75, 449.5, 443.25, 450.5, 159.5, 
188.125, 153.875, 186, 153.875, 148.875, 150.75, 162.125, 159, 
160, 153.125, 155.125, 148.375, 160.125, 154.5, 154.125, 158.75, 
164.25, 18.375, 18.375), sy = c(824.25, 824.5, 602.25, 526.5, 
603.5, 584, 665.625, 576.5, 647.625, 663.875, 621.875, 635.125, 
620.125, 615.125, 624.75, 620.75, 624.25, 624.625, 616.875, 616.125, 
624, 620.25, 640, 643, 629.125, 638.625, 637.75, 636.375, 631.75, 
636, 625.125, 632.875, 628.875, 629.125, 628, 633.5, 626.5, 624.75, 
627.75, 623.25, 624.25, 628.125, 422.5, 422.125, 436, 343, 307.125, 
426.5, 497, 361.375, 308.375, 114.5, 569.625, 405.75, 295, 117.625, 
285.75, 282.75, 311.875, 313.125, 241, 227.375, 227, 215.375, 
210.25, 201, 194, 193.625, 180.625, 186.375, 170.875, 168.375, 
356.75, 375.375, 345.875, 625.375, 547.25, 705.125, 522.25, 539.25, 
529.875, 537.625, 523.25, 520.375, 526.375, 537.125, 527.875, 
527.375, 524.375, 540.125, 520.125, 517.625, 506.75, 527.625, 
589, 586.375, 585.5, 579.75, 573.625, 575.125, 576.5, 570.125, 
561.25, 575.375, 570.5, 571.125, 557.5, 509.125, 504.875, 502.875, 
501.875, 497.875, 499.875, 500.125, 498, 494.25, 491, 496.25, 
482.375, 511.375, 506.125, 347.375, 349.25, 356, 331.125, 324.875, 
327.125, 326, 324.625, 319.625, 308.625, 300.125, 303.75, 355.625, 
258.125, 376.375, 240.5, 407.375, 571.5, 319.25, 320.125, 322.75, 
325.375, 326.625, 329.375, 331, 336.75, 334.875, 339, 338.5, 
344.25, 345.125, 351.625, 352.25, 358.5, 361.25, 367.625, 373, 
379, 379.625, 388.125, 393.125, 407.625, 415.25, 423.875, 419.875, 
418, 414.375, 414.375, 414.375, 413.75, 411.5, 411.375, 410.25, 
411.125, 412.625, 412.75, 415.5, 420.5, 425, 433.625, 442.625, 
450.375, 462, 472.875, 484.625, 501.75, 517.375, 530.25, 544.875, 
560.125, 553.25, 551.875, 380.75, 395.625, 381, 391, 385.125, 
387.875, 378, 385.5, 382.125, 381.375, 377.75, 618.875, 492.5, 
615.875, 491.875, 621.5, 605.25, 575.875, 578.5, 570.5, 567.25, 
555.5, 561.75, 549.375, 553.5, 552.875, 550, 546.25, 512, 17.625, 
17.5), time = c(0, 53, 10412, 10852, 11726, 14766, 16355, 16635, 
17103, 18089, 21190, 21270, 21390, 21470, 21596, 21769, 21839, 
22345, 22433, 22486, 22589, 22749, 23603, 23736, 23848, 23914, 
24028, 24081, 24199, 24492, 24607, 24727, 24805, 24898, 24939, 
25019, 25081, 25134, 25253, 25386, 25464, 25677, 43614, 43734, 
44773, 46319, 47376, 49082, 50808, 51354, 51943, 52676, 53701, 
54234, 54610, 55010, 56108, 56374, 56804, 56830, 57054, 57120, 
58576, 59016, 59118, 59371, 59444, 59750, 59824, 60024, 60122, 
60428, 62233, 62379, 63029, 64002, 64355, 64848, 69213, 69439, 
69509, 69602, 69722, 69762, 69892, 69945, 70013, 70079, 70157, 
70490, 71192, 71405, 71479, 71559, 72044, 72377, 72537, 72670, 
72837, 72922, 73148, 73260, 73466, 73559, 73650, 73787, 74120, 
81336, 81362, 81460, 81726, 81766, 82032, 82220, 82233, 82266, 
82346, 82545, 82878, 85603, 85909, 92315, 92395, 92493, 92759, 
92877, 92983, 93045, 93098, 93171, 93397, 93460, 93860, 103099, 
103859, 104463, 105183, 114168, 116248, 117497, 117630, 117816, 
117896, 118039, 118119, 118268, 118348, 118490, 118570, 118696, 
118762, 118886, 118952, 119084, 119150, 119269, 119322, 119434, 
119487, 119578, 119644, 119741, 119807, 119924, 119977, 120312, 
120378, 120497, 120563, 120682, 120735, 120861, 120914, 121007, 
121073, 121174, 121227, 121316, 121382, 121475, 121528, 121623, 
121676, 121767, 121833, 121916, 121982, 122089, 122142, 122214, 
122254, 122640, 122893, 129695, 129815, 129952, 130285, 130387, 
130627, 130792, 130880, 131346, 131388, 131468, 151617, 152110, 
152471, 153071, 154769, 154835, 155339, 155472, 155686, 155806, 
155873, 156059, 156133, 156226, 156287, 156327, 156395, 156768, 
170859, 170939), Point.ID = 1:224), .Names = c("Stroke.ID..starttime.", 
"sx", "sy", "time", "Point.ID"), row.names = c(NA, -224L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am not sure you can retain numeric format when what you want to put in the column is...well...not a number. Alternatively you can store them both as a numeric vector, within the dataframe and than access each component singularly for your calculations.

Comment: so you don't think it is possible to have a numeric column with a 2D-vector at all?

Comment: You can not convert a `character` to a `numeric` or `integer`, `character` is in the highest position in the data type list of R. See this link for more info 
http://nicercode.github.io/2014-02-13-UNSW/lessons/01-intro_r/data-structures.html

Comment: @Flugmango, can please use dput your data?

Comment: @Abdou what do you mean?

Comment: Run `dput(mydf)` in the R console. Then copy and paste the output somewhere in your question; so that someone can use that to actually create the same data in their R console.

Comment: @Abdou ok, thanks, I have done it

Comment: That's not running properly. Please do instead: `dput(data.frame(mydf, stringsAsFactors=F))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I think you can do is the following.

If `df` is your data frame:

```
df$coord <- mapply(function(x,y) c(x,y), df$sx, df$sy, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

The output is:

```
   Stroke_ID_.starttime.      sx      sy  time Point_ID            coord
1                      0 667.750 824.250     0        1   667.75, 824.25
2                      0 668.500 824.500    53        2     668.5, 824.5
3                  10412 231.250 602.250 10412        3   231.25, 602.25
4                  10412 194.375 526.500 10852        4 194.375, 526.500
5                  11726 226.125 603.500 11726        5 226.125, 603.500
6                  11726 212.250 584.000 14766        6   212.25, 584.00
7                  16355 422.125 665.625 16355        7 422.125, 665.625
8                  16355 468.250 576.500 16635        8   468.25, 576.50
9                  17103 406.750 647.625 17103        9 406.750, 647.625
10                 17103 420.000 663.875 18089       10 420.000, 663.875
```

Now bear in mind, the column coord is a list of numerical vectors.
To prove it:

```
class(df$coord[[1]])
[1] "numeric"
```

So if you want to access the *sx* for the first point, you have to use the following syntax:

```
df$coord[[1]][1]
[1] 667.75
```

Comment: I guess this is pretty much what I had in mind, even if not 100%, but I guess I can live with that! I can access the "point" with df$coord[[1]] and this is still numeric, so I can make calculations with this

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it differently by defining a point as the concatenation of `sx` and `sy` separated by a comma (`,`). For example, we can have `Point1` defined as `3, 4`; i.e. (3,4) in mathematical terms.

You can illustrate this with your own data.frame. I have renamed it `Points_df`. You can create a `Coordinates` column that concatenates `sx` values to `sy` values separated by a comma.

```
Points_df$Coordinates <- apply(Points_df[,c("sx","sy")], 1, FUN=function(x) {
  paste(x[1],x[2],sep=", ")
})
```

Take a peek at the data

```
Stroke.ID..starttime. sx     sy     time Point.ID Coordinates   
 0                     667.75 824.25  0   1        667.75, 824.25
 0                     668.50 824.50 53   2        668.5, 824.5
```

Now create a helper function that takes two points and calculates the distance between them.

```
distanceCalcultor <- function(Point1, Point2) {
  Point1 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Point1,split=", ")))
  Point2 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Point2,split=", ")))
  distance <- sqrt((Point1[1]-Point2[1])^2+(Point1[2]-Point2[2])^2)
  return(distance)
}
```

Check the distance between the coordinates 1 and 5

```
distanceCalcultor(Points_df$Coordinates[1],Points_df$Coordinates[5])
[1] 493.7238
```

I hope this complements handsomely.